# Fixed Header area not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header that I need to fixed to top and change it's background while scroll down. Do I need to use jQuery? I tried to use position:fixed but it's not working properly.

Here are my code samples,

```css
header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo-div {
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-panel">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4  col-sm-4 logo-div">
      <a href="#"> <img id="headerLogo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5 col-sm-6  menu pull-right">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class=" navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class=""><a href="#" class="border-rg menu-item forget-password" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forget-password">Sign In <i class="fa fa-user-o user-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="menu-item border-rg">Retrieve Quotes</a></li>
              <li>
                <i class="fa fa-bars menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Original look.[image]

It just looks this way now.
[image]

Comment: try `header { width: 100%; }`

Comment: try to change your header class like this header{position:fixed; left:20px; top:20px;}

Comment: @MichaelCoker: Tried but it went out with wrapper container.

Comment: honestly, if you're after a distinct header then you're better off having two divs (maybe flex box) rather than using fixed. Fixed is really only appropriate if you don't mind it overlapping other stuff.

Comment: you can study from 
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: fixed;` on the header, and use this function:

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
   if($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
     $("header").css('background-color', 'transparent');
   }
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
     $("header").css('background-color', 'darkgrey');
   }
});
```

To change the header colour if the div's not at the top.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() { 
   if($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
     $("header").css('background-color', 'transparent');
   }
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
     $("header").css('background-color', 'darkgrey');
   }
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>stuff stuff</header>
<div id="scrollable">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet ultricies sapien, a volutpat risus. In nec tempus diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed et neque erat. Etiam pulvinar metus augue, nec facilisis
  ipsum semper vitae. Maecenas tincidunt feugiat ex, sit amet eleifend orci placerat vel. Vivamus ac ullamcorper ipsum, vehicula lacinia lacus. Nam auctor, nisi sit amet vehicula fringilla, ex orci aliquam neque, in fermentum velit diam ac purus. Nunc
  sed efficitur dui. Curabitur enim metus, rutrum ut mattis non, molestie a nisi. Vivamus non fermentum purus. Integer ornare enim ut commodo scelerisque. Cras tincidunt tortor feugiat libero facilisis mattis. Etiam facilisis est eu massa bibendum porttitor.
  Proin tincidunt orci ut pellentesque euismod. Donec pretium velit ac dolor rhoncus, eu scelerisque nisl blandit. Pellentesque dapibus et lacus auctor tincidunt. Quisque sit amet ullamcorper dolor. Cras scelerisque congue vehicula. Nam aliquet suscipit
  ex, id pulvinar augue suscipit at. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque bibendum, turpis eget suscipit scelerisque, diam mi facilisis quam, et vehicula nisi nisl faucibus dui. Aenean id malesuada velit. Sed pellentesque,
  nulla at pulvinar fringilla, augue neque suscipit augue, non porta nulla erat in leo. Nunc sollicitudin dolor quis posuere lobortis. Donec at aliquam neque. Integer nec urna odio. Suspendisse maximus molestie sem pharetra elementum. Vestibulum at elit
  id lorem venenatis finibus. Sed luctus nulla dignissim mauris euismod, quis blandit augue rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Nullam bibendum arcu risus, nec scelerisque nisl pharetra ut. Praesent consectetur eleifend lectus, in ornare ipsum. Cras aliquam quis
  urna quis commodo. Cras fermentum lacinia risus, quis fringilla turpis vestibulum eu. Pellentesque luctus iaculis efficitur. Nam et mauris condimentum, blandit ante quis, vulputate sapien. Mauris mollis odio id dolor pharetra, nec volutpat nibh cursus.
  Nam sed lacinia libero, eget hendrerit elit. Donec laoreet sapien non dolor congue, nec pellentesque libero semper. Vestibulum efficitur at ipsum vitae ultricies. Ut nec neque vestibulum, varius augue quis, feugiat libero. Sed feugiat lectus id rhoncus
  laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec ac malesuada justo, pharetra maximus nunc. Nam hendrerit neque vel blandit gravida. Aenean congue facilisis elit, a eleifend quam pharetra nec.
  Integer id luctus ipsum, id aliquet nunc. Integer pulvinar iaculis eros, ultrices ullamcorper tellus congue in. Suspendisse blandit ullamcorper ipsum, sed cursus nulla lobortis venenatis. Maecenas venenatis pretium diam, quis laoreet libero dictum eu.
  Fusce elementum mattis vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut cursus libero. Integer eget tempor dui, ut volutpat tortor. Sed sodales dolor a leo ultricies, id mollis augue convallis. Duis at egestas lectus.
  Nunc ultricies magna quis justo euismod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet ultricies sapien, a volutpat risus. In nec tempus diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed et neque
  erat. Etiam pulvinar metus augue, nec facilisis ipsum semper vitae. Maecenas tincidunt feugiat ex, sit amet eleifend orci placerat vel. Vivamus ac ullamcorper ipsum, vehicula lacinia lacus. Nam auctor, nisi sit amet vehicula fringilla, ex orci aliquam
  neque, in fermentum velit diam ac purus. Nunc sed efficitur dui. Curabitur enim metus, rutrum ut mattis non, molestie a nisi. Vivamus non fermentum purus. Integer ornare enim ut commodo scelerisque. Cras tincidunt tortor feugiat libero facilisis mattis.
  Etiam facilisis est eu massa bibendum porttitor. Proin tincidunt orci ut pellentesque euismod. Donec pretium velit ac dolor rhoncus, eu scelerisque nisl blandit. Pellentesque dapibus et lacus auctor tincidunt. Quisque sit amet ullamcorper dolor. Cras
  scelerisque congue vehicula. Nam aliquet suscipit ex, id pulvinar augue suscipit at. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque bibendum, turpis eget suscipit scelerisque, diam mi facilisis quam, et vehicula nisi nisl faucibus
  dui. Aenean id malesuada velit. Sed pellentesque, nulla at pulvinar fringilla, augue neque suscipit augue, non porta nulla erat in leo. Nunc sollicitudin dolor quis posuere lobortis. Donec at aliquam neque. Integer nec urna odio. Suspendisse maximus
  molestie sem pharetra elementum. Vestibulum at elit id lorem venenatis finibus. Sed luctus nulla dignissim mauris euismod, quis blandit augue rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Nullam bibendum arcu risus, nec scelerisque nisl pharetra ut. Praesent consectetur
  eleifend lectus, in ornare ipsum. Cras aliquam quis urna quis commodo. Cras fermentum lacinia risus, quis fringilla turpis vestibulum eu. Pellentesque luctus iaculis efficitur. Nam et mauris condimentum, blandit ante quis, vulputate sapien. Mauris mollis
  odio id dolor pharetra, nec volutpat nibh cursus. Nam sed lacinia libero, eget hendrerit elit. Donec laoreet sapien non dolor congue, nec pellentesque libero semper. Vestibulum efficitur at ipsum vitae ultricies. Ut nec neque vestibulum, varius augue
  quis, feugiat libero. Sed feugiat lectus id rhoncus laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec ac malesuada justo, pharetra maximus nunc. Nam hendrerit neque vel blandit gravida. Aenean
  congue facilisis elit, a eleifend quam pharetra nec. Integer id luctus ipsum, id aliquet nunc. Integer pulvinar iaculis eros, ultrices ullamcorper tellus congue in. Suspendisse blandit ullamcorper ipsum, sed cursus nulla lobortis venenatis. Maecenas
  venenatis pretium diam, quis laoreet libero dictum eu. Fusce elementum mattis vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut cursus libero. Integer eget tempor dui, ut volutpat tortor. Sed sodales dolor a leo ultricies,
  id mollis augue convallis. Duis at egestas lectus. Nunc ultricies magna quis justo euismod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet ultricies sapien, a volutpat risus. In nec tempus diam. Interdum et malesuada
  fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed et neque erat. Etiam pulvinar metus augue, nec facilisis ipsum semper vitae. Maecenas tincidunt feugiat ex, sit amet eleifend orci placerat vel. Vivamus ac ullamcorper ipsum, vehicula lacinia lacus. Nam auctor,
  nisi sit amet vehicula fringilla, ex orci aliquam neque, in fermentum velit diam ac purus. Nunc sed efficitur dui. Curabitur enim metus, rutrum ut mattis non, molestie a nisi. Vivamus non fermentum purus. Integer ornare enim ut commodo scelerisque.
  Cras tincidunt tortor feugiat libero facilisis mattis. Etiam facilisis est eu massa bibendum porttitor. Proin tincidunt orci ut pellentesque euismod. Donec pretium velit ac dolor rhoncus, eu scelerisque nisl blandit. Pellentesque dapibus et lacus auctor
  tincidunt. Quisque sit amet ullamcorper dolor. Cras scelerisque congue vehicula. Nam aliquet suscipit ex, id pulvinar augue suscipit at. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque bibendum, turpis eget suscipit scelerisque,
  diam mi facilisis quam, et vehicula nisi nisl faucibus dui. Aenean id malesuada velit. Sed pellentesque, nulla at pulvinar fringilla, augue neque suscipit augue, non porta nulla erat in leo. Nunc sollicitudin dolor quis posuere lobortis. Donec at aliquam
  neque. Integer nec urna odio. Suspendisse maximus molestie sem pharetra elementum. Vestibulum at elit id lorem venenatis finibus. Sed luctus nulla dignissim mauris euismod, quis blandit augue rutrum. Nulla facilisi. Nullam bibendum arcu risus, nec scelerisque
  nisl pharetra ut. Praesent consectetur eleifend lectus, in ornare ipsum. Cras aliquam quis urna quis commodo. Cras fermentum lacinia risus, quis fringilla turpis vestibulum eu. Pellentesque luctus iaculis efficitur. Nam et mauris condimentum, blandit
  ante quis, vulputate sapien. Mauris mollis odio id dolor pharetra, nec volutpat nibh cursus. Nam sed lacinia libero, eget hendrerit elit. Donec laoreet sapien non dolor congue, nec pellentesque libero semper. Vestibulum efficitur at ipsum vitae ultricies.
  Ut nec neque vestibulum, varius augue quis, feugiat libero. Sed feugiat lectus id rhoncus laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec ac malesuada justo, pharetra maximus nunc. Nam hendrerit
  neque vel blandit gravida. Aenean congue facilisis elit, a eleifend quam pharetra nec. Integer id luctus ipsum, id aliquet nunc. Integer pulvinar iaculis eros, ultrices ullamcorper tellus congue in. Suspendisse blandit ullamcorper ipsum, sed cursus
  nulla lobortis venenatis. Maecenas venenatis pretium diam, quis laoreet libero dictum eu. Fusce elementum mattis vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ut cursus libero. Integer eget tempor dui, ut volutpat tortor.
  Sed sodales dolor a leo ultricies, id mollis augue convallis. Duis at egestas lectus. Nunc ultricies magna quis justo euismod tempor.

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a flexbox to created a fixed header with a scrollable body.

Stuff like `fixed` and `absolute` should really be for stuff that you don't mind overlapping other stuff. Like small icons that scroll back up to the top, etc.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#body {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div id="header">
    stuff
  </div>
  <div id="body">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam lobortis augue et ligula porta auctor. Donec ac metus sollicitudin, tristique arcu nec, consectetur orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse dictum leo quis odio sollicitudin ultrices. Praesent urna ligula, accumsan vel imperdiet in, sagittis at lorem. Integer luctus consectetur vestibulum. Etiam sollicitudin facilisis sem, pretium facilisis sem placerat ut. Donec sit amet lacinia dolor, varius mattis mi. Donec sed est pharetra, rhoncus tortor non, fringilla dolor. Praesent elit magna, semper sed commodo vitae, auctor id nisi. Phasellus vel dignissim orci. Maecenas tellus lacus, sollicitudin at felis et, facilisis euismod nibh. Donec a leo tellus.

Fusce dolor erat, malesuada at sapien a, pretium mattis sapien. Morbi ut risus ut diam cursus rhoncus. Fusce eu molestie ipsum, venenatis lobortis metus. Vivamus eget egestas lectus. Proin iaculis porta nibh, at ullamcorper augue aliquam nec. Sed faucibus nisl nec risus porttitor eleifend. Donec ultricies nulla ac metus consectetur, sit amet faucibus risus dignissim. Vestibulum vitae nisi pellentesque, vulputate nibh sed, ullamcorper mi. Nunc ultricies nisl at nulla sollicitudin ullamcorper. Vivamus egestas placerat tempus. Nam fermentum eu felis non semper. Aliquam nunc justo, viverra ac eleifend ut, pulvinar vitae risus. Vestibulum sollicitudin non ipsum in tempus.

Mauris ut massa eget mauris varius faucibus. Suspendisse tellus felis, posuere vel accumsan a, molestie venenatis libero. Sed vel nunc in libero varius dapibus consectetur a sapien. Duis sagittis pellentesque sem, eu bibendum odio consectetur aliquet. Aliquam et purus risus. Nulla a posuere libero. Sed aliquet convallis efficitur. Curabitur aliquam, turpis id tempor molestie, est quam egestas ipsum, at feugiat nunc nulla sed elit. Aliquam venenatis convallis lacus, in ornare erat dignissim vel. Morbi ac rhoncus leo, in feugiat massa. Suspendisse non velit in dolor lacinia vulputate eu a ex. Ut tristique rhoncus consequat. Quisque malesuada aliquet massa, at viverra odio sagittis eu. Duis posuere a velit quis porttitor. Phasellus eu libero ultricies, tincidunt arcu placerat, commodo quam. Donec quis orci laoreet, auctor ligula at, dictum mi.

Etiam dictum nisl orci, sit amet venenatis purus viverra ut. Donec hendrerit felis id convallis placerat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed aliquam lacus ut nisi feugiat, et ultricies augue consequat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In tincidunt metus a justo placerat porta. Donec porta id est in scelerisque. Cras semper massa neque, vitae ultrices mauris pulvinar id. Fusce eu luctus neque, ac tincidunt eros. Nullam eleifend tincidunt arcu a cursus. Curabitur dictum semper augue, euismod varius neque vestibulum vitae. Nam tortor lectus, tempus non auctor id, sollicitudin nec elit. Duis ut odio et tortor maximus varius. Sed fringilla sit amet ipsum hendrerit cursus. Duis id urna dolor.

Mauris tincidunt odio non maximus condimentum. Vivamus velit enim, interdum eget feugiat nec, tincidunt sed sem. Nullam imperdiet erat urna, ut maximus odio bibendum eu. Morbi porttitor ante eget malesuada hendrerit. Nulla pulvinar risus posuere, placerat ligula ac, pharetra neque. Vivamus id lorem id risus ullamcorper sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse luctus, velit vitae tristique consectetur, lorem urna rutrum mi, vitae tristique est velit posuere diam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce dictum lobortis metus, et posuere arcu venenatis vel.

Nunc odio mi, varius at vulputate in, accumsan ac justo. Nunc vel blandit odio. Vivamus et suscipit velit, a dignissim libero. Sed vel velit ante. Mauris scelerisque, elit at tempor eleifend, orci elit placerat nisl, ut suscipit augue turpis et ipsum. Pellentesque efficitur sapien mauris, non venenatis justo commodo eget. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer sed nibh nec sem interdum tristique quis sit amet massa. Suspendisse vel mauris magna. Integer id sapien ac libero lacinia ullamcorper nec eget enim. Nullam eget nunc non lectus congue condimentum. Etiam fermentum consectetur felis, et pulvinar nibh iaculis id. Ut felis lacus, consequat id mattis eu, volutpat quis urna. Sed nisi neque, malesuada quis nibh sit amet, aliquam vehicula tellus. Cras pharetra nisi nec metus pretium ullamcorper in quis leo. Etiam mi diam, venenatis non lorem a, suscipit tempor est.

Sed sit amet finibus ligula. Cras sit amet magna et nisi elementum tristique eget quis metus. Aenean efficitur ac sem vulputate efficitur. Nullam felis nibh, dictum ac iaculis non, molestie eu urna. Donec arcu turpis, tempor sed risus at, pharetra varius elit. Praesent cursus justo metus, at tristique ligula suscipit at. Aenean vel pellentesque eros. Aenean sit amet nisl vehicula, posuere felis in, egestas lectus. Praesent sollicitudin dictum diam sed lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi dapibus scelerisque lorem, eget vehicula tellus condimentum eget. Phasellus scelerisque leo nec risus imperdiet molestie. Suspendisse nec lacus at magna tristique pellentesque nec vel libero.

Proin in finibus erat. Ut sodales urna non purus gravida luctus. Quisque imperdiet eros scelerisque felis auctor ultrices. Phasellus lacinia enim et ligula sollicitudin vestibulum. Quisque semper libero quis mauris feugiat volutpat. Mauris ac eleifend diam, ac semper risus. Duis eget luctus neque, at molestie nisl. Nulla volutpat maximus vulputate. Nunc pretium velit in neque vestibulum, blandit lacinia augue efficitur. Maecenas sem sem, condimentum sed dolor vulputate, gravida lobortis dolor. Aenean efficitur nibh vitae lacus gravida ornare. Mauris sagittis ex lacus, ut congue augue interdum in. Morbi nec congue odio. Quisque eleifend mi at convallis interdum. Nunc at congue dolor, quis blandit nunc. Maecenas molestie sollicitudin sem in scelerisque.

Donec sed pellentesque urna, eu fringilla tellus. Nullam at fermentum eros. Nam viverra est at est mattis, lobortis volutpat massa accumsan. Nunc vel faucibus risus. Vivamus a urna hendrerit, ullamcorper tellus aliquet, sagittis felis. Sed eget nisl tempus, congue nisi nec, accumsan purus. Donec molestie metus eget lorem imperdiet facilisis. Donec vulputate ut sem rutrum tincidunt. Nulla at lectus at dui imperdiet tincidunt non blandit enim. Vivamus accumsan risus eget porttitor aliquet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Nulla maximus blandit mauris, vel consectetur leo auctor et. Mauris non diam a neque tincidunt euismod. Donec non augue porttitor, imperdiet metus eget, laoreet ex. Nulla ut accumsan magna, id venenatis est. Nunc tempus dolor non velit vestibulum, sit amet finibus risus pulvinar. Sed egestas dapibus turpis, eu scelerisque quam sollicitudin id. Vivamus libero magna, congue quis volutpat eget, vestibulum nec ex. Curabitur auctor eros in ultrices scelerisque. Vestibulum lacinia hendrerit euismod. Nam ut ultricies eros. Mauris sed tortor mi. Mauris dolor metus, euismod sit amet quam sed, efficitur dapibus risus. Quisque aliquet molestie nisl id semper. Sed venenatis augue vitae cursus volutpat. In id nulla vel quam vehicula ornare.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great. Do you any method for changing red background color to white while scrolling down?

Comment: Why not just leave it white? If you need a changing background depending on scroll you might need to use javascript. Most customers/visitors won't really care too much about a visually stunning website. Simplicity and sleep is key nowadays. I want to find x and get to x within seconds.